# Ansible privilege escalation become with sudo -i

Tags: ansible

I can become root on host only with command "sudo -i". I must be root to make some changes on this host. How can I become root with this method using ansibleplaybook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For privilege escalation, [become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) allows you to specify both `become_method` and `become_flags`:

```
- name: My playbook
  hosts: myhosts
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_flags: '-i'
  tasks:

  - name: My task
    [..]
```